# Converting LastLogon to DateTime format

Tags: powershell, active-directory

My objective is to get a list of users from my domain with the following info:

-Display name
-Country
-Manager Name
-Last login date

I am running the following script, and everything looks good except for the LastLogon.  It outputs the time into a bunch of random numbers like "129948127853609000".  How can I convert this to DateTime format?

```
Search-ADAccount -UsersOnly -SearchBase "OU=International,DC=mycompany,DC=com" -AccountDisabled:$false | Get-ADUser -Properties Name, manager, LastLogon | Select Name, manager, LastLogon | export-csv C:\Australia.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`DateTime.FromFileTime` should do the trick:

```
PS C:\> [datetime]::FromFileTime(129948127853609000)

Monday, October 15, 2012 3:13:05 PM
```

Then depending on how you want to format it, check out [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) datetime format strings.

```
PS C:\> [datetime]::FromFileTime(129948127853609000).ToString('d MMMM')
15 October
PS C:\> [datetime]::FromFileTime(129948127853609000).ToString('g')
10/15/2012 3:13 PM
```

If you want to integrate this into your one-liner, change your `select` statement to this:

```
... | Select Name, manager, @{N='LastLogon'; E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}} | ...
```

Comment: Cool, but how would I inject that into this script?

Comment: one line answers make me heavily randall

Comment: Note that LastLogonDate and LastLogonTimestamp are only updated when the previous authentication request occurred longer ago than the value for the attribute ms-DS-Logon-Time-Sync-Interval (default 14 days). 

To know whether the user account or computer object has authenticated within the last two weeks (or you if need to know the actual last logon time), check the value of the LastLogon property of the object. Unfortunately, LastLogon is not replicated among domain controllers, so you will need to query all DCs in your environment to determine the most recent LastLogon value.

Answer (score 13):

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true} -Properties Name,Manager,LastLogon | 
Select-Object Name,Manager,@{n='LastLogon';e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}}
```

Comment: What is this technique called? `@{n='LastLogon';e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}`

Comment: Sorry for the double post but I found the answer myself. For anyone else who is curious, it's called a calculated property. N = name and E = expression.

Comment: If it wasn't clear from @HiTech 's comment, `N` and `E` are shorthand that are recognized by PowerShell as equivalent to actually using `Name` and `Expression`, respectively, as the keys of the hashtable given to define the calculated property.

Answer (score 8):

LastLogon is the last time that the user logged into whichever domain controller you happen to have been load balanced to at the moment that you ran the GET-ADUser cmdlet, and **is not replicated across the domain**. You really should use LastLogonTimestamp if you want the time the last user logged in to any domain controller in your domain.

Comment: This is true, however it should also be noted that the LastLogonTimeStamp is not 100% accurate. The LastLogonTimeStamp is up to 9-14 days inaccurate. To get the true LastLogon, you must query the LastLogon property for the account on all domain controllers in the domain

Answer (score 3):

Use the **LastLogonDate** property and you won't have to convert the date/time.
**lastLogonTimestamp** should equal to **LastLogonDate** when converted.
This way, you will get the last logon date and time across the domain without needing to convert the result.

Answer (score 1):

While lastlogon is not replicated, lastlogontimestamp is.    lastlogontimstamp is not human readable (milliseconds since windows epoch)

Here is a one liner that ACTUALLY solves it without querying every server.

get-adcomputer -filter 'operatingsystem -like "*server*" -and enabled -eq "true"' -prop lastlogontimestamp|select name, lastlogontimestamp, @{N='LastLogon'; E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogontimestamp)}}

Answer (score 0):

It is important to know that LastLogonDate is not replicated.   LastLogonTimestamp is so it is important that you use timestamp on large domains