# Active Directory Strange Attribute Value

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm getting info about a user in Active Directory using this code:

```
    SearchResultCollection searchResults = null;
    string activeDirFilter = getActiveDirFilter();
    DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry();

    DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(dirEntry)
    {
        PageSize = 100,
        Filter = activeDirFilter,
        SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree
    };
```

This code works fine and I'm getting these attributes:

```
LASTLOGON
130388757393977187

PWDLASTSET
130378422326246669

LASTLOGONTIMESTAMP
130380275331980403
```

However, I can't make sense of the value, does anyone know how to decode those numbers to time stamps?

**EDIT:
The values can't be seconds since epoch, because 130388757393977187 seconds = 4 131 858.64 millenniums.**

It can't be ticks either, because 130388757393977187 = 413 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out:

You need to use

```
long x = 130388757393977187;
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(x);
```

Comment: Answer found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091719/converting-lastlogon-to-datetime-format

Answer (score 1):

You currently have the `Unix Timestamp` you should convert it into DateTime object and print it.

```
public static DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime(double unixTimeStamp)
{
    // Unix timestamp is seconds past epoch
    System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0,System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
    dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime();
    return dtDateTime;
}
```

Comment: I think this would work if the numbers were smaller.

I get an OutOfRange exception when using 130388757393977187.

Comment: But doublel.MaxValue = 1.7976931348623157E+308.
Does that = 1.7976931348623157x10^308 ?
If so, this is more than enough space to store 130388757393977187, why am I getting an OutOfRange error?

Comment: @Backwards_Dave, Maybe this article would help, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/565593/How-to-get-the-REAL-lastlogon-datetime-from-Active

Comment: I get An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Value to add was out of range.

on dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime();

Comment: The problem is that 130 388 830 889 255 041 seconds =
4 131 860.97 millennium which when used as an input to UnixTimeStampToDateTime() returns an output much greater than DateTime.MaxValue.

why am I getting such a large number from AD?

Could it be microseconds or something?

Comment: Ok your method could work if you edited according to this:
A file time is a 64-bit value that represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 A.M. January 1, 1601 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). The system records file times when applications create, access, and write to files.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx